# Planting a flower plant under a huge mango tree

Tags: flowers, planting, urban-gardening

I have got this flower tree that i found near a pond. Dunno what it is bit its beautiful, so i have decided to get a small one and plant it in my garden.

But i have about 6 mango trees in an area of about 400sq.m. i am concerned that there's nothing left in the soil for my plants. I wont cut the mango trees. I saw my aunt plant a rose after slightly cutting the root of a similar tree. She made a small "incision" and then put the rose plant in it(few of its roots). It is healthy now. It was a long time ago and so i need details of this can be replicated.[image: the image attached is of the flower plant that i want to, well, plant]

Comment: You found it as a 'wild' plant by a pond? It looks very much like a canna lily (not a true lily) and a cultivar at that! Are you sure it's wild?

Comment: Its not. I never said its "wild". I found it but so did others. You can see the people in the background. Its a artificial pond. Its used to wash trucks and mining vehicles. It was not planted there, it grew on its own.

Comment: Okay. Yes, I saw the people in the background but because you wrote it was beside a pond and it's a prized ornamental flower, it didn't make sense to me. Where I live (near Vancouver Canada) , a pond either means 1) a small body of water (with frogs and water birds) in a bit of wilderness *or* 2) a pond maintained by city or town government in a park. I didn't think you'd be digging up plants from a park so I thought it must be like the first type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your comment, yes, I'm certain this is a valued ornamental canna lily. Since the pond you mention is just used for washing trucks and mining vehicles I think it's an excellent idea to save it before it's ruined by contaminated water.

If it's growing without anyone planting it or caring for it, it sounds like you live in a tropical or semi-tropical part of the world. Your user profile doesn't say but it's warm enough for mangoes! Rather than cutting a place in the soil to plant it, I'd suggest planting it in a large container or pot instead. I don't know what units of volume is used in your country so I'll do my best. Since you said "flower tree" - it sounds like a large canna lily and I'd suggest containers from roughly 20 litre (5 gallon) up to 80 litre (20 gallon) size. They don't have to be pretty or expensive. If you can get hold of a wooden barrel and cut it in half, you'd have 2 containers.

I'll provide some links to planting and growing calla lilies in containers. It would be better if I knew your country so I could find links that might be better related for your area. Calla lilies have rhizomes and transplanting any now, you might find they don't do as well at first. But they'll recover and next year be more spectacular. You should deadhead the flowers when finished (remove the entire dead flower, not just the petals). Otherwise, it will try setting seed and drain strength and food storage from the rhizome - unless you want to save seed.

They're heavy feeders so mix in well composed plant matter into the soil. Generally, people should use commercial potting soil when growing plants in containers. They might be expensive where you live so if you don't use potting soil, make sure to add composted plant matter or something to keep the soil from being heavy and compacting down. Water well and often if your area has prolonged dry periods. Whatever you use for fertilizer in your area, it's good to add some by mixing in water regularly to your plants.

I hope this is helpful. Containers are a good choice as you can put them where the plants would do best and look gorgeous. Please save as many of the canna lilies as you can. Good luck!

[Growing Canna Lilies](http://www.dirtonmyhands.com/canna_grow.html)

[Containers For Canna Lily Plants: How To Plant Cannas In Pots](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/bulbs/canna/planting-cannas-in-pots.htm)

[Designing an easy container garden using Tropicanna cannas](http://youreasygarden.com/designing-an-easy-container-garden-using-tropicanna-cannas/)

Comment: I am from India. Monsoon just arrived. It is been raining for last two days but enough sunlight gets through. I live in a mining town. The soil is basically iron. Drop a phone and small pebbles stick to the speaker grill. The plant is a big bush/hedga about 5ftx2ft.